# Homology computations of $\partial \Delta[n]$ using normalized chain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

I have to compute the homology group of the abstract simplicial set $\partial \Delta[n]$ using normalized chain complexes.

I know that the nondegenerate $k$-simplices of $\partial \Delta[n]$ are $\Delta[n]^{\text{nd}}_k$ for $k \neq n$ (which are the strictly increasing maps $[k] \to [n]$) and $\varnothing$ otherwise.

Moreover, I proved that the homology of $\Delta[n]$ is the same as the one of a point, that is, $H_0(\Delta[n]) = \mathbb{Z}$ and it is $0$ otherwise.

However, I don't understand how to put everything together. It seems clear that for $k=n$ the homology of the boundary is $0$, but what happens for $k = n+1, n-1$ in the chain complex?

Of course, I know that I have to get $H_k(\partial \Delta[n])=\mathbb{Z}$ for $k=0, n-1$ and $0$ otherwise, but how can I deduce this from the homology of the abstract simplex $\Delta[n]$?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should be able to figure this out topologically. Or is that the point, to avoid topology and work entirely combinatorically? May I ask what resources you're using to study the combinatorial side of simplicial homology?

Comment: @FShrike I am following a course where unfortunately we are not using specific books as references. For example, I know how to compute the homology of the torus using other means, e.g. its description as semisimplicial set, but here I have to understand this approach of considering the normalized chain complex of $\Delta[1]/ \partial \Delta[1] \times \Delta[1]/ \partial \Delta[1]$.

Comment: Ok. So I guess taking geometric realisations is considered cheating

Comment: @FShrike I would say so. I know for example that the geometric realization $| \Delta[n] | = \Delta^n$ of $\Delta[n]$ is contractible, but this is not the point of the exercise.

Comment: Do you know how to list the degenerate and non-degenerate simplices of dimension k of $\Delta^n$?

Comment: @user17786 I have written in my notes that $\Delta[n]^{\text{nd}}_k$ are the subsets of $\{0, \cdots, n\}$ with $k+1$ elements. Do you mean this, or are you talking about topological simplices?

Comment: Is the normalized chain complex the one spanned by nondegenerate simplices?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S^{n-1}$ be the complex with $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $0, n-1$ and $0$ in all other degrees. Let $i_n$ be the unique nondegenerate $n$-simplex of $\Delta^n$. Then the nondegenerate $(n-1)$-simplices of $\partial\Delta^n$ are $d^n_i(i_n), i=0,\ldots, n$ and $c = \sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^jd_j(i_n)$ is a cycle in $N(\partial \Delta^n)$, since it is a boundary in $N(\Delta^n)$. Define a chain map $f\colon S^{n-1}\to N(\partial\Delta^n)$ via $f_{n-1}(k) = kc$ and in degree $0$ $\mathbb{Z}\to N(\partial\Delta^n)_0$ by sending the generator of $\mathbb{Z}$ to the basis element corresponding to the $0$th vertex. There is a retraction $r\colon N(\partial\Delta^n)\to S^{n-1}$. In degree $0$ this maps $N(\partial\Delta^n)_0\to \mathbb{Z}$ the basis element corresponding to the $0$th vertex to $1$ and all other basis elements to $0$. In degree $n-1$ it is given by $r_{n-1}\colon N(\partial\Delta^n)\to \mathbb{Z}$,
$$r_{n-1}(d^n_j(i_n)) = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }j<n,\\
1 &\text{if }j=n.
\end{cases}$$
I claim that $f\circ r$ is homotopic to the identity. An increasing map $\alpha\colon [k]\to [n]$ corresponds to an increasing sequence $(i_0,\ldots, i_k)$ and this is nondegenerate if all elements are distinct. We define a chain homotopy on basis elements by
$$s_k(i_0,\ldots,i_k) = \begin{cases}
(-1)^{k+1}(i_0,\ldots, i_k, n) &\text{if } i_k<n,\\
0 &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
and we extend this to a linear map $N(\partial\Delta^n)_k\to N(\partial\Delta^n)_{k+1}$. I leave it to you to check that this gives the desired chain homotopy.

One can also use the long exact sequence in homology. Let $\mathbb{Z}[n]$ be the complex with $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $n$ and $0$ in all other degrees. Then there is a short exact sequence of complexes
$$0\to N(\partial\Delta^n)\to N(\Delta^n)\to \mathbb{Z}[n]\to 0,$$
since $\partial\Delta^n$ and $\Delta^n$ have the same nondegenerate $k$-simplices for $k\neq n$, $\partial\Delta^n$ has only degenerate $n$-simplices and $\Delta^n$ has exactly one nondegenerate $n$-simplex. Now if you already know the homology of $N(\Delta^n)$ it is easy to read off the homology of $N(\partial \Delta^n)$ from the long exact sequence in homology.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write down the basis for each term and the boundary maps. For example, if $n =2$, you have $C_2=0, C_1=\mathbb Z\{[1,2],[2,3],[1,3]\}, C_0 = \mathbb Z\{[1],[2],[3]\}$, and $$\partial_1=\left(\begin{matrix}-1&0&-1\\
1&-1&0\\
0&1&1
\end{matrix}\right).$$
Similarly $\partial_0 = \left(\begin{matrix}1&1&1\end{matrix}\right).$
Now just calculate kernels and images. Since you've already done this for te full simplex (not just the boundary) you know that for most cases the kernel of the outgoing operator will equal the image of the incoming one. So the only real work to do is to analyze what happens in the top dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is: I didn't proceed in this way to compute the homology of the full simplex $\Delta[n]$, but I used a semisimplicial homotopy from its identity to the constant map $0$. Hence I was wondering if there is a way of deducing the result for the boundary with less computations? After all, since the nondegenerate $k$-simplices of the boundary are basically the same of the ones of $\Delta[n]$ apart from $k=n$, maybe there is a faster way to conclude...? I don't know, though.

Comment: It is definitely possible to show this complex is homotopy equivalent to one with a single generator in dimension $n-1$ and one in dimension $0$, though that seems like a lot of work when another argument is available.